# How to tell if two objects are identical?

Tags: javascript, object

I mean not *equal*, but literally *one*....two things pointing to the same place in memory.

For example, `a` and `b` here should theoretically be identical...`b` is a sort of pointer to `a`.

```
var a = function(){alert("hi");}

var b = a;
```

`===` is not the answer....two things can be the same in every way but not literally the same object in memory.

**Edit:** `===` IS the answer! Silly me.

Comment: `a === b` returns `true`...

Comment: maybe you can specify how you wish to use them

Comment: Do either of these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: There is no built-in operator for evaluating the "*similarity*" of 2 distinct objects. `a === b` evaluates whether `a` and `b` are references to the exact same object.

Comment: If `===` is not the answer (which it is) then there is no answer. Or lets say the answer is: There is no way.

Comment: Down-voted because `===` IS the answer

Comment: actually there is no identical objects which === can not cover them. I have used it for the very same use, and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two identical objects never return true when compared. They really have to be "one".

[image: Preview]

Comment: May I note for additional clarity for future readers that `a = {val: 1}; b = a;` yields `b === a` as `true`.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

> An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object.

Comment: Oh...and that is the piece I did not know about the `===` operator...turns out it IS the answer!

Comment: Because the code example is exactly what I needed to see to be sure! Hard code is much more persuasive than documentation, although together the two answers are 100% complete. If you're on SO for the rep, btw, you need a hobby.